# Using a regular function with the name of an inline function in C

Tags: c, function, inline

Assume I have two files:

#### 1.c

```
inline int test(int in){
 return in+1; 
}

int get();

int main(){
 return get();
}
```

#### 2.c

```
int test(int in){
  return in+9;
}

int get(){
 return test(5);
}
```

Compiling it with `gcc 1.c 2.c` goes smoothly with no errors.

Is this defined behaviour? i.e `test` in `1.c` is different from the other function and we essentially have 2 `test` functions in generated in code?

Comment: try to call get in the `main`.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline : *If a non-static function is declared inline, then it must be defined in the same translation unit. The inline definition that does not use extern is not externally visible and does not prevent other translation units from defining the same function. This makes the inline keyword an alternative to static for defining functions inside header files, which may be included in multiple translation units of the same program.*

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I did, edited accordingly above. Compiles fine and the definition in 2.c is used as expected. 14 is returned in main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inline` copy of `test` in 1.c doesn't actually constitute a external function definition, allowing for `test` in 2.c to be used by the program.  If you were to call `get` in the `main` function and print the result, you would get the value 14.

If you were to call `test` from the `main` function, is could use either version of the function.  Which one it does use is **unspecified**.

The mechanics of `inline` are specified in section 6.7.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), paragraphs 6 and 7:

> *6* A function  declared  with  an `inline` function  specifier  is  an *inline  function*.  Making  af unction  an  inline  function
> suggests  that  calls  to  the  function  be  as  fast  as
> possible.<sup>138)</sup>  The extent to which such suggestions are
> effective is implementation-defined.<sup>139)</sup>
>
> *7* Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function.  For a function with external linkage,  the  following  restrictions
> apply:  If  a  function  is  declared  with  an `inline` function
> specifier, then  it  shall  also  be  defined  in  the  same
> translation  unit.  **If  all  of  the file  scope  declarations  for  a
> function  in  a  translation  unit  include  the `inline` function
> specifier  without `extern`,  then  the  definition  in  that
> translation  unit  is  an *inline definition*.  An inline  definition
> does  not  provide  an  external  definition  for  the  function, and
> does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit.**
> An inline definition provides an alternative to an external
> definition, which a translator may use to implement any call to the
> function in the same translation unit.  **It is unspecified whether a
> call to the function uses the inline definition or the external
> definition.**<sup>140)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 138 ) By  using,  for  example,  an  alternative  to  the  usual
> function  call  mechanism,  such  as  ‘‘inline substitution’’.  Inline  substitution  is  not  textual  substitution,  nor  does  it
> create  a  new  function.Therefore,  for  example,  the  expansion  of
> a  macro  used  within  the  body  of  the  function  uses  the
> definition  it  had  at  the  point  the  function  body  appears,
> and  not  where  the  function  is  called;  and identifiers  refer
> to  the  declarations  in  scope  where  the  body  occurs.
> Likewise,  the  function  has  a single  address,  regardless  of  the
> number  of  inline  definitions  that  occur  in  addition  to  the
> external definition.
>
> 139 ) For example, an implementation might never perform inline
> substitution, or might only perform inline substitutions to calls in
> the scope of an `inline` declaration.
>
> 140 ) Since  an  inline  definition  is  distinct  from  the
> corresponding  external  definition  and  from  any  other
> corresponding inline definitions in other translation units, all
> corresponding objects with static storage duration are also distinct
> in each of the definitions.

As an example of unspecified behavior, if you added the following line to `main`:

```
printf("test(3)=%d\n", test(3));
```

If you compile in gcc with `-O0` you'll get `test(3)=12`.  If you compile with `-O1` or higher you'll get `test(3)=4`.

Answer (score 1):

From this link on [inline functions](https://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html)

> You can have a separate (not inline) definition in another
> translation unit, and the compiler might choose either that or the
> inline definition.

So, that's why compiler did not give any error.

Comment: Thank you, so this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not undefined. As stated in the other answer - *unspecified*. It is different